# Register device on Azure notifications hub

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, azure-notificationhub

I'm developing an application using Ionic & capacitor. My backend is Azure functions (nodejs) javascript, i'm able to get the device token using the below code:

```
PushNotifications.addListener(
      'registration',
      (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
        alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
      },
    );
```

This token I send to my backend, but i don't know how to save it in Azure Notifications Hub?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is stored on your app backend. Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) for more information.

Let me know if there are further questions on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use `azure-sb` to successfully register the device and send notifications, sample code here: https://github.com/mpodwysocki/azure-notificationhubs-node-sample/blob/main/src/index.ts